# PyQT signal from another script

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I have two python scripts. The first script contais a PyQt GUI which shows the status of my switch ports. To  display the status it consults a database that contains the full information of the ports. The second script is responsible for making the necessary changes to the database when the state of a port is altered.
I need to know how to send a signal or something similar when the database is updated.

**PyQt script**

```py
  from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
  import sqlite3
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(300, 170)
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 200))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.mac = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.port = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ip_addres = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.name = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.actionUpdate = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionUpdate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionUpdate"))
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionUpdate)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionUpdate, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("activated()")), self.update)

        def update(self):

            con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
            cursorObj = con.cursor()
            sql_query = "SELECT * FROM switch"
            cursorObj.execute(sql_consulta)
            row = cursorObj.fetchone()

            self.mac(_translate("MainWindow", row[0] None))
            self.ip_addres.setText(_translate("MainWindow", row[1], None))
            self.name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", row[2], None))
            self.port.setText(_translate("MainWindow", row[3], None))

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app =QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The other script is executed when a change occurs in the switch and updates the database.
I need a way to update the interface when a change occurs, without the need to press the update button.

**The other script**

```py
import sqlite3
import sys
if __name__ =="__main__":
    con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    cursorObj = con.cursor()
    sql_query = "UPDATE switch SET mac ='" + str(sys.argv[0]) + "', ip_addres = '" + str(sys.argv[1]) + "', name = '" + str(sys.argv[2]) + "', port ="  + str(sys.argv[3]) 
    cursorObj.execute(sql_update)
    con.commit()
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc with that is enough?

Comment: it seems that you have not read the link, the code you provide is not an MRE

Comment: @eyllanesc That's OK?

Comment: one python process could implement a TCP server, and the other process could send data to the serve every time the DB changed?

If the solution should only work under linux you might send a signal to the other process to notify about an update (e.g. SIGHUP)